# Seeing holes in mesh while in texture mode

Tags: mesh

I have just started teaching myself 3D modeling so that I can start making some simple 3D games in Unity. I am already familiar enough with code to start making things, but I lacked the 3D model assets. I been teaching myself Blender and created some very simple models. The problem I am finding is that I get what appears to be holes in the mesh. For example if I put the model into Texture mode I see what looks like a Face that is see through or another color. If I start moving Vertices in Edit mode I can make the hole disappear.

Just wondering what I might be doing wrong to cause this problem. I know you are suppose to try and keep all faces quads so that is what I continue to do.   Basically all I am doing right now is making a flat model in a Top Ortho view and then extruding to add a 3rd dimension to the model. Am I doing things wrong? Just making a simple model of a ghost yet I somehow have this other section that appears to be a different color when viewed in texture mode.

[image]

Here is the same model in Solid Shading mode
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help with this.

Comment: You may consider to share the file link. For example, to upload it [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/).

Comment: Could be normals facing the wrong way. Select all in edit mode and Ctrl-N

Comment: Could also be some duplicated vertices, try to remove doubles with all vertices seleted in edit mode with W menu and "remove doubles". It it's not normals or doubles, we'll probably need the .blend

Comment: It looks like it could be faces inside the mesh, connecting the wing vertex loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there mainly are two problems in your mesh.

- Face normals are inverted.
- You are using material node which is invalid to use by current render engine.

[image]

To fix them, you can switch to Edit Mode, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to re-calculate normals, then deal with the material node as you wish.

Comment: You and the others that mentioned a problem with the normals are correct. This is really my first shot at 3D modeling so I am not sure exactly what I did wrong. I first tried Control N and that just gave gives me a cursor with a white line. Not sure what that does. I found that if I hit N I get the hidden menu to come out. It is there that I found the button that shows you the orientation of the normals. Most were ok but some seemed to be facing inward. I ended up going one by one and flipping them. I don't know or understand what you mean by Material Node. I was just following beginner....

Comment: tutorials on 3D modeling. All I really did was add points in a Topdown view and then extrude everything out to add thickness. What am I doing wrong that made so many of the faces in the wrong direction? Just trying to fully understand before I attempt to make more complex models.

Comment: It's hard to say what you did wrong. For a short explaination of normals, it's the direction a face is pointing at. Blender uses this to know how the light will bounce on the face. Only one side of a face is supposed to be visible. The normal is supposed to be pointing outward where the surface seen is outside the mesh. If the face is flipped, the bouncing light is "flipped" too, resulting in something visualy strange.  short but hopefully clear.

Comment: Creating and editing a shape rarely results in a perfect mesh. We all have to check our normals. I think all 3D artists have had the same problem, wondering why :)

Comment: I actually understand now. I just wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong when building the model. I think I am good now. Thank you all.